# Learning Math from Old Hard Books

Tags: soft-question, math-history

Does any one have a syllabus for how math was taught in UK in the 1800s?

For example, a curriculum from the time that made use of the following book (as an example), Toddhunters Treatise on Differential Calculus:

https://archive.org/details/treatiseondiffer00todhuoft

I recall seeing a detailed answer where a precalculus syllabus of books (totalling like 3,000 pages) was posted, but I cannot find it.

Wondering if someone could outline a way to go about this?

I am interested in exploring the old way of learning math as a matter of personal interest.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you googling in google-books, restricted to 19th century? The first thing I tried, namely [Toddhunter + textbook](https://www.google.com/search?q=Todhunter+textbook&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1899), had several hits on the first page that suggested trying things such as {"annual report" + education + math} and {calendar + university + math}. Probably in a minute or two you'll be able to refine these to obtain several fairly decent word-and/or-phrase searches for what you want.

Comment: Thanks @DaveL.Renfro, I did not actually try Google books - that is a great idea!

Thank you, I will take a look through google books, can already see some interesting insights.

Comment: You'll probably want to narrow the date range sometimes. If you're looking within a date range of roughly 5 years or less, it might be a good idea to not use searches involving phrases (that is, remove the quotes around the words in a phrase), as sometimes .pdf rendering is such that you'll miss some items. And for authors, mostly just use the last name, since not all books have the author's first name on the title page and while google usually includes a full name in the entry, it sometimes doesn't even have the first name. **(continued)**

Comment: Finally, when searching for something very specific, you sometimes (paradoxically) get more hits if you include an additional (relevant) search word. For other tips that might be helpful ("might" because this is for something different than what you're looking for), see [this answer](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/12807/264). For examples of how much can be found by such searches, see the following answers: [answers 1](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/344/264) and [answer 2](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/13859/264) and [answer 3](https://mathoverflow.net/a/251036/15780).

Comment: Thanks a lot @DaveL.Renfro, I already found a great bibliography that I can spend time looking through [here](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Solutions_of_the_Examples_in_Charles_Smi/ESxAAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Todhunter+KEY+TO+EXERCISES&pg=RA1-PA24&printsec=frontcover)

I am mainly interested in trying to understand how folks from those ages picked up math, and how a curriculum may have looked back in the day.

I did see a great comment on one of the stack exchange websites that outlined a complete syllabus based on footnotes from some book, but foolishly did not bookmark it!

Comment: I completely forgot about book lists at the end of many 1800s texts. Some of these lists are especially long (40, 50, or more pages). Also endorsements of textbooks in advertisements at the end of some (other) texts. Also of likely interest: **A Bibliographical Catalogue of Macmillan and Co.'s Publications from 1843-1889** (1891 -- [google-books](https://books.google.com/books?id=fo0YAAAAMAAJ) and [internet archive](https://archive.org/details/bibliographicalc00macm)) *AND* [**Early American Textbooks, 1775-1900**](https://archive.org/details/ERIC_ED264601) (1985).

Comment: Googling the title of that Macmillan catalogue (e.g. [search 1](https://www.google.com/search?q=Bibliographical+Catalogue+of+Macmillan+Publications+1843-1889&tbm=bks) and [search 2](https://www.google.com/search?q=Bibliographical+Catalogue+of+Macmillan+Publications+1843-1889)) may lead to other things of possible interest. See also [this "dictionary" of older terms](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/12421/264), which maybe I should add to at some point.

Comment: Thanks again for those links @DaveL.Renfro, this is awesome - feels like I am walking back through time looking at these digital scans. The booklists will really help me discover the reference books used at the time - wonder what forgotten knowledge lays within them. There seem to be some real gems there, seems like the books were written at a more advanced level then what we see today (at least here in present day Britain).